# asterisk outbound caller id

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to set the caller id number for an outbound call.

My asterisk .call file looks like this:

```
Channel: SIP/flowroute/1234567890
Context: test
Extension: 1234567890
Priority: 1
```

Here's my extensions.conf:

```
[test]
exten => _1NXXXXXXXXX,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=8005552222)
exten => _1NXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@flowroute)
exten => _1NXXXXXXXXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
```

When I receive the call, the caller id number is 1-206-445-6979, even though the CDR log has both `src` and `clid` set to `8005552222`.  I'm using flowroute as my carrier.  Is there something wrong on their side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I got this working:

.call file:

```
Channel: SIP/flowroute/1234567890
CallerID: "Test" <8005552222>
Context: test
Extension: 888
Priority: 1
```

extensions.conf:

```
[test]
exten => 888,1,Playback(hello-world)
```

Note that the extensions.conf context does not include a dial application.  In fact, when it was included two outgoing calls were placed with some very strange results.

Answer (score 3):

Your config is correct.  Your carrier is likely preventing you from setting an arbitrary CID number; check with them.

Comment: I agree this is likly the problem. With our carrier we had to sign an agreement with them that allowed us to set our outbound caller id. They do this to prevent telemarketing compaines from playing with their numbers and confusing the parties being called. Contact your carrie and they should be able to help you get setup so you can set this.