# Change the caller id from my asterisk server

Tags: asterisk

I successfully set up an asterisk server.  When people call my asterisk server via PSTN, the server will place another PSTN call to my phone at `33344455555`.  When I receive the call, my phone shows that I'm receiving a call from `4169998888`, which is the number of my DID/SIP account on the asterisk server.  However, I don't want to see 4169998888 as the caller, I would like to see the phone number of the person who's trying to call me.  Is there a ways to configure my asterisk server to show this?

This is what part of my extensions.conf currently looks like

```
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/4169998888/33344455555,30,g)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Hangup
```

I tried using Set(CALLERID(num)=somenumber) but it didn't take effect.  I looked at [this question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/122681/asterisk-outbound-caller-id) but I don't have any `.call` files.  What else can I do?

Comment: Your carrier doesn't allow you to set up arbitrary Caller ID, it pushes your predefined DID on your SIP account. There is a SIP code 302 - moved temporarily, which you can send, and it works on some SIP providers, but you got to check with them...

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in to the site of the VOIP provider and add your phone number to the list of caller id's and confirm it. After you confirmed the caller id, you can use `Set(CALLERID(num)=somenumber)` to make calls. If you VOIP provider doesn't allow you to add caller id's (which will look very strange to me), it's not possible unfortunately. I'm using the provider browsercalls for landline numbers and stuntcalls for mobile numbers. They are both very cheap (less then a cent per minute) and also let you add caller id's.

WARNING: You have to add the landcode before the number. Example:
`Set(CALLERID(num)=+31612345678)`

Answer (score 0):

Your VoIP provider will likely not allow you to set a CID name / number which is not associated with your account.  You can't just add names/numbers from other accounts.  (Otherwise you could spoof "Police <911>").

You should consider having the outbound call read the originating CID into the audio stream on pickup by your cell.